# HTML button act like key pressed from keyboard, and function on certain object or entire website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The button should act like: Enter, Arrow Keys, Space ...
Already tried some examples.
Here's one:

```
var e = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 8});
$("#target").keypress();
```

Comment: how `e` variable is binded with `$("#target").keypress();`?

Comment: Could you please provide more information on what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to connect the html button with the functions described to a swf file.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the `keypress` event is not triggered for non-printing keys, so the arrow keys will not work with `.keypress()`.

From the jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

> The `keypress` event is sent to an element when the browser registers keyboard input. This is similar to the `keydown` event, except that modifier and non-printing keys such as Shift, Esc, and delete trigger `keydown` events but not `keypress` events. Other differences between the two events may arise depending on platform and browser.

Instead, you would want to use `.keydown()` or `.keyup()`. But, instead of trying to trigger a `keydown` or `keyup` event when your button is clicked, why not just write a function that does what you want and call that function whenever the key is pressed or your button is clicked?

For example, say you want a character to move left when you push the left key or your left key button, you could write this function:

```
var moveLeft = function() {
   alert('Moving character left one position');
};
```

Then, you can call that function whenever the left key is pressed or your left button is clicked.

```
$('#left-btn').click(moveLeft);

$('body').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        moveLeft();
    }
});
```

**Working example:**

Inspect your browser's JavaScript console when clicking the left or right buttons or pressing the left or right arrow keys.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var moveLeft = function() {
    console.log('Moving left!');
  };

  var moveRight = function() {
    console.log('Moving right!');
  };

  $('body').keydown(function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 37:
        moveLeft();
        break;
      case 39:
        moveRight();
        break;
    }
  });
  
  $('#left-btn').click(moveLeft);
  
  $('#right-btn').click(moveRight);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="left-btn">&larr;</button>
  <button id="right-btn">&rarr;</button>
</div>
```